# Setting a client receiveTimeout for CXF service above 4 minutes

Tags: java, web-services, timeout, esb, jboss-esb

I have generated an CXF service and set timeouts for `120000ms = 2min` for both:

```
requestContext.put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", 120000);
requestContext.put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", 120000);
```

It is working fine, I have tested it for `20s, 1min, 3min` - everytime it is waiting for response exacly that amout of time.

However problem apears when I wanted to set it on `5min`. Service is waiting for resposne only for `~240800ms = ~4min`.

I'm calling jboss esb service. This one lasts max `5min`. CXF service is called from inside of simple `.jar` application from my PC, so there is no other servers/containers between (like tomcat etc).

Any ideas to fix my timeout settings?

Using a `Apache CXF 3.0.1`

**EDIT**

What I realized now that I'm getting 2 diffrent messages depends on my timeout settings:

- If I set it to `<=4min` (via my or @pedrofb method), after that amount of time I'm getting:

  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
  at    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
  at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)

  Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://esb:8080/MyService/ebws/Category/MyService: Read timed out
- if I set it to `>4min` or `0`, I'm getting:

  javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No response received for service [Category:MyService], Told not to retry.

To be honest, I'm pretty confused what is an expected result (first one, I think)

**EDIT 2**

I have tested `MyService` via `SoapUI`. I have set a `5min` timeout there and shoot with sample request.

Again, after little more then 4 min I'm getting a:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
  <env:Fault>
     <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>No response received for service [Category:MyService], Told not to retry.</faultstring>
  </env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However when I look into log of Jboss ESB I have no exceptions, no errors, `MyService` last a 1 min more (about 5 min) and return normal response - which is confirmed by audit tool (which register every request to my esb - with response and time).

I think that this point on that what @pedrofb mentioned in comment. Any suggestions what this can be?

Comment: Can the server be limiting the response to four minutes?

Comment: I have check that - service is responsing after about `4,5min` with normal, expected message, server timeout is set to `5 min` which confirms that

Comment: Maybe  your problem is similar to this http://rayploski.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/jbossesb-setting-up-long-running.html The client receives a timeout while the ESB continue processing. In this case it is needed to configure  `org.jboss.soa.esb.ws.timeout` in ESB

Comment: @pedrofb Bingo! Param was set to exacly `240000`. Everything working perfectly well now. Can you edit your answer to let me accept it? Btw which method is better to set timeouts? Via `RequestContext` or like you posted via `HttpClientPolicy`

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad!. I suggest to use CXF specific parameters, because in JIRA ticket they say that `RequestContext` parameters are not standarized and may change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe your problem is similar to this http://rayploski.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/jbossesb-setting-up-long-running.html The client receives a timeout while the ESB continue processing. In this case it is needed to configure `org.jboss.soa.esb.ws.timeout` in ESB

To configure client timeout, seems using `requestContext` parameters are not standarized see https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1166. CXF team suggest they can change

Try using CXF specific parameters for timeout

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(proxy);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(0);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(0);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

The complete list of parameters is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html).  0 means no timeout.

Comment: I've set my receive timeout to 300000ms (5 min) using this method. It's been 10 and it still hasn't timed out. Any ideas?